# std::destroy_at differences between major compilers?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, std

Using compiler explorer with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct test
{
  test(int i)
  {
    std::cout << "test::test("<<i<<")\n";
  }
  ~test()
  {
    std::cout << "~test()\n";
  }
};

template<>
void std::destroy_at(test* p) 
{
  std::cout<<"std::destroy_at<test>\n";
  p->~test();
}

int
main ()
{
  auto sp = std::make_shared<test>(3);
  return 33;
}
```

Gives the expected output using C++20 with gcc x86-64 or clang x86-64:

```
Program returned: 33
test::test(3)
std::destroy_at<test>
~test()
```

But x64 msvc v19.32 gives:

```
Program returned: 33
test::test(3)
~test()
```

As if the std::destroy_at has no effect here.

Is this conforming behavior, my misunderstanding or a msvc non conformance or misconfiguration?

Comment: AFAIK `shared_ptr` is not required to use `std::destroy_at` in its destrcutor.

Comment: However, it's interesting, because standard explicitly demands that when object is created via `std::make_shared`, it is later destroyed with `pv->~U()`, not `std::destroy_at`. https://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.create#7.11 And to add to confusion, both gcc and clang only call `std::destroy_at` in C++20 mode (UB): https://godbolt.org/z/zMPK31EET, but not when in C++17 mode (no UB): https://godbolt.org/z/saxE5o19f

Answer (score 5):

Specializing standard library functions is [UB since C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Function_templates_and_member_functions_of_templates).

Comment: "It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library function template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited."Are you sure?

Comment: @RaymundHofmann That was until C++20

Comment: @RaymundHofmann you can only add specialization for class types, not functions.